# Instantiate Subclass from instance of Parent Class

Tags: objective-c

No previous knowledge of AFNetworking is required, but it might be helpful.

I'm using AFNetworking and I want to create a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation that has a couple of extra properties and methods.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm using factory methods of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to generate my AFHTTPRequestOperations and I obviously don't want to change any of the core code in the AFNetworking library.

So what I want to do, is something like this:

```
@implementation VP_AFHTTPRequestOperation : AFHTTPRequestOperation

+ (id)instantiateUsingAFHTTPRequestOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)reqOp {
    //I want to create an instance of VP_AFHTTPRequestOperation using the reqOp
    self = reqOp; //I can't just do this, but I don't know what to do
    return self;
}

- (void)mySubclassMethod { /* ... */ }
@end
```

I'd appreciate any advice

Comment: Why? What do you need to add and why?

Comment: Great question, and I may very well need to do something other than what I've asked for. I need to add 2 properties and overwrite a method of AFHTTPRequestOperation (so I figured I'd need to subclass it) - but I don't want to change core AFHTTPRequestManager factory methods that generate AFHTTPRequestOperation's. So I was hoping that I could generate a subclass instance of AFHTTPRequestOperation using a factory method on my subclass, but this may very well be not the right approach.

Comment: @Adam: So what exactly do you need to add to `AFHTTPRequestOperation`?

Comment: I want to add functionality to `setCompletionBlockwithSuccess`... (in my subclass I'll add in a couple of lines and then call `[super setCompletionBlock...]` that copies the success and fail blocks passed into the function into 2 properties that I will add to my subclass.

Comment: Why? The blocks are already stored by the operation.

Answer (score 0):

subclass AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and make it return something good in `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest`

no modification of any framework code needed AFAICS

```
@interface VP_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager 
@end     

@implementation VP_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

+ (instancetype)manager { 
    return [[[self class] alloc] init]; 
}

- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                success:(void (^) (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    VP_AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[VP_AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = self.responseSerializer;
    operation.shouldUseCredentialStorage = self.shouldUseCredentialStorage;
    operation.credential = self.credential;
    operation.securityPolicy = self.securityPolicy;

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

    return operation;
}

@end
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean to use self in the class method, you are correct - but that still doesn't really help. Also worth pointing out that I am using the new AFN, it no longer uses AFHTTPClient.

Comment: and you don't wanna just override AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: I don't want to modify any core code of AFNetworking - it's an external dependency that I'm actually loading using cocoapods, so when there's an update to it, I don't want any of my code mixed in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want by subclassing `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and using your subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in the override of `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure`. It's succinctly described in the docs:

> To change the behavior of all request operation construction for an
>   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager subclass, override
>   HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure.

Comment: what I said ;) for some reason I can't deduce he doesn't want this :P

Comment: @Daij-Djan - I didn't want to have to subclass AFHTTPRequestOperationManager as well. But it sure looks like the only way to go about it is to subclass AFHTTPRequestOperationManager as well.